# Error: Unexpected response data from server - user Profile properties displays

Tags: development, 2013, user-profile, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I get the mentioned error message when i try to display the User Profile properties by using JSOM(Java Script Object Model) Error: Unexpected response data from server. The error occurs for around 1 min or 5-6 refresh , after that it works as expected . What could be the reason ?
Please find the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var personProperties;

    // Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');

    function getUserProperties() {

        // Replace the placeholder value with the target user's credentials.
        var targetUser = "VMDEV\\XXXX";

        // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

        // Get user properties for the target user.
        // To get the PersonProperties object for the current user, use the
        // getMyProperties method.
        personProperties = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUser);

        // Load the PersonProperties object and send the request.
        clientContext.load(personProperties);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
    }

    // This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
    function onRequestSuccess() {

        // Get a property directly from the PersonProperties object.
        var messageText = " \"DisplayName\" property is "
            + personProperties.get_displayName();

        // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
        if (personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['FirstName'] != "")
        {
            messageText += "<br />\"FirstName\" property is "
                + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['FirstName'];
        }
        // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
        if (personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'] != "") {
            messageText += "<br />\"Department\" property is "
                + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'];
        }

        // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
        if (personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['WorkPhone'] != "") {
            messageText += "<br />\"WorkPhone\" property is "
                + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['WorkPhone'];
        }

        // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
        if (personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['SPS-Department'] != "") {
            messageText += "<br />\"SPS-Department\" property is "
                + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['SPS-Department'];
        }


        // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
        if (personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Fax'] != "") {
            messageText += "<br />\"Fax\" property is "
                + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['Fax'];
        }

        // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
        if (personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['HomePhone'] != "") {
            messageText += "<br />\"HomePhone\" property is "
                + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['HomePhone'];
        }

        // Get a property from the UserProfileProperties property.
        if (personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['CUS-CSIFS'] != "") {
            messageText += "<br />\"WXY-CSXYZ\" property is "
                + personProperties.get_userProfileProperties()['CUS-CSIFS'];
        }

        $get("results").innerHTML = messageText;
    }

    // This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
    function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
        $get("results").innerHTML = "Error: " + args.get_message();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: WXY-CSXYZ is a custom property , but it doesnt seem to be working .  How do i access the custom property using JSOM ?

Comment: The error occurs for around 1 min or 5-6 refresh , after that it works as expected . What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the property names which you want to fetch. Just include your custom property in the `profilePropertyNames` array:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    // Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadUserData, 'SP.UserProfiles.js'); 
  });

  var userProfileProperties = [];

  function loadUserData(){

    //Get Current Context   
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    //Get Instance of People Manager Class
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    //Properties to fetch from the User Profile
    var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName","PictureURL"];  

    //If you are on On-Premise:
    var targetUser = "VMDEV\\XXXX";

    //Create new instance of UserProfilePropertiesForUser
    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(clientContext, targetUser, profilePropertyNames);
    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    //Execute the Query.
    clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

  }

  function onSuccess() {

    var messageText = "\"Preffered Name\" property is " + userProfileProperties[0];
    messageText += "\"PictureURL\" property is " + userProfileProperties[1];

    alert(messageText);

  }

  function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
  }
```

For more details, see my blog [here](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html)